# Split a column into multiple columns consisting of a single string in R

Tags: r, encoding, binary, analytics, xgboost

I want to encode a set of categorical values into binary values. First I converted them to binary using `intToBin(x$y)`

Now I want to split this binary into separate columns

```
0101
0100
0110
0101
0101
0100
```

to

```
0 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

and so on and at the same time want to convert it into numeric values. It should be scalable to more number of strings.

I have used `separate(x$y, sep = l)` for converting. But I am getting an error. Please help me in correcting the code or providing any other alternative. The purpose of changing the values to binary is to build a model using `XGBoost`.

[An example of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYyzB.png)

Comment: To get a matrix, `as.integer(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x$y), split="")))` will work in base R, though there may be a more efficient method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, how do I split it into 4 separate columns?

Comment: `stringr::str_split_fixed(x$y, "", 4)`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
d=c("0101","0111","0011","1101")  
# Split into columns
d2=do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(d), split="")) #see elmo's comments
# Make numeric and transform to dataframe (instead of matrix)
d2=as.data.frame(apply(d2,2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = c("0101","0100","0110","0101","0101","0100")
data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(strsplit(a,"")),nrow = 4)))
```

OR

```
data.frame(t(sapply(a, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"")))))
#You may get a warning about identical row names
```

OR if you want something that works when the number of digits of elements in `a` is not uniform,

```
a = c("01101","0100","0110","0101","0101","0100") #Note 1st element has 5 digits
b = sapply(a, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"")))
data.frame(t(sapply(b, '[', seq(max(sapply(b,length))))))
#You may get a warning about identical row names
```